# identifier GetClientRect not found

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have a small program (In visual studio 2010 professional) that compiles and runs in debug mode despite GetClientRect calls being underlined in red in the code editor. The code does not compile in release mode though with an error message 'identifier not found' reported for all the calls to GetClientRect.

I'm able to reproduce this in a console program with the following, except this I cannot even compile in debug mode now. Any hints?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, NULL);
   RECT r;
   GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's impossible to explain with the provided info.  Look at the WinUser.h file and see what happened to it.

Comment: Try ::GetClientRect instead of just GetClientRect.

Comment: Spot on, Hans. I had made some unintentional changes to the file.

Answer (score -1):

Invoking GetClientRect makes no sense in a console, since console app don't have a Window object.

Comment: They can also find windows from other processes and get information about those - which appears to be what the OP is doing here. Console apps can also have their own windows (in addition to the console one - so long as they have a suitable message loop, as any window-based app must have); while it's somewhat unusual practice, there's nothing in Win32 that prevents it.